# Need Time efficient data structure to store computed value using values from different maps that have intersecting key type but same value type

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a **problem**

I have 4 classes
Need to maintain **3 maps**

```
class A
{
};

class B
{
};

class D
{
    int d1;
    int d2;
};

std::unordered_map<A, D> m1;
std::unordered_map<B, D> m2;
std::unordered_map<std::pair<A, B>, D> m3;
```

Note: These maps are not updated frequently.

**Problem**
1. For object of A: **a**, object of B: **b**, and object of pair of object of **a** and object of **b**,
2. Need to get an object of D: **d** such that

```
d.d1 = std::min( m1[a].d1, m2[b].d1, m3[std::pair(a,b)].d1 );
d.d2 = std::min( m1[a].d2, m2[b].d2, m3[std::pair(a,b)].d2 );
```

Note: The values may not exist in which case they will be skipped, eg: m1[a] does not exist, for a pair(a, b), than `min( m2[b], m3[std::pair(a,b)] )` will be used

The **simple solution** is
1. find

`m1[a], m2[b], m3[pair(a, b)]`

**three** look-ups
2. perform minimum on d1 and d2
3. Get **d**

I can not save every **b** for every **a**, as the number of possible keys of A and B is huge

**Question**
1. I need to store this info in such a structure such that for a pair of **a** and **b**, I can get **d**, in less than three look-ups, I need to reduce the time for look-ups to the minimum while the space may be increased.
2. Also, the time of updating that structure can be more than updating the three maps.
3. If anyone knows any such data structure, please provide the name or the link or some explanation. Thanks.

Regards

Comment: Why do you need all this? What is the problem that this solution is supposed to solve? Please take some time to read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then think about how you can improve your question.

Comment: The problem is to save time using the fact that there are different keys that have intersecting entities and for a key containing all the entities, one can find a value that depends on values corresponding to the different keys. The aim is to construct all such values in the beginning( increasing the space ) but then use less time while retrieving afterwards.

Comment: *The problem is to save time* -- Have you actually measured how much time you would save?

Comment: I have measured the time it would take to perform the simple solution mentioned but I don't know how much time I would save using the new structure as I don't know any such structure. I want a structure that can save time based on the number of entities in the key type and number of key types possible, here the number of entities is 2, and the number of possible key types is 3.

Comment: Why do you think doing 3 lookups is bad? a lookup in ```unordered_map``` is amortized O(1) so doing 3 lookups is not that bad, and doing 2 or 1 instead of 3 is not going to give you that massive improvement. TL;DR I don't know if there's a better approach than what you mentioned, but if there is, I don't think it'll be that much better.